# WP prioritize displaying author's posts first before displaying admin posts

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php 

    $author_query = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'author' => $author->ID,
    );

    $author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
    while($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <br> 
    <?php endwhile;

 ?>
```

The code above will only show the posts of current Author,

So basically like this, the setting is I want to show 5 posts, and currently the Author has only 2 posts so output will be:

```
1. Author Post
2. Author Post
```

but I still want to show the post of Admin and Editor, but I want to prioritize showing the Author posts first.

So basically it should become like this;

```
1. Author Post
2. Author Post
3. Admin Post
4. Editor Post
5. Admin Post
```

As you can see it prioritize showing the author's posts first before showing the other posts of admin and editor. Thats what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below modified code

```
<?php 
// Get author posts
$author_query = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'author' => $author->ID,
    );

$authorpostswpquery =  new WP_Query($author_query);
$authorposts = $authorpostswpquery->posts;

//Get admin role users
$admins = get_users(array('role' => 'administrator'));

//Get editor role users
$editors = get_users(array('role' => 'editor'));

/* Combine editor and admin roles users and loop over 
final array to collect admin and editor user ids */
$finalDatausers = array_merge($admins,$editors);
foreach($finalDatausers as $finalDatauser){
    $admineditorIds[] = $finalDatauser->ID;
}

$admineditorIds = array_unique($admineditorIds);

//Get admin and editor posts
$admineditorquery = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'author__in' => $admineditorIds,
);
$admineditorpostswpquery = new WP_Query($admineditorquery);
$admineditorposts = $admineditorpostswpquery->posts;

//create new empty query and populate it with the other two
$wp_query  = new WP_Query();
// combining posts from author query and admineditor query to single query
$wp_query->posts = array_merge($authorposts,$admineditorposts);
//populate post_count count for the loop to work correctly
$wp_query->post_count = $admineditorpostswpquery->post_count + $authorpostswpquery->post_count;

 while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <br> 
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: This is also what  I did, double query. This kind of approach works so I will accept it as an answer. Thanks